# Is it possible to set the name of an external metric for a HorizontalPodAutoscaler from a configmap? GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I am modifying a deployment which autoscales using a HorizontalPodAutoscaler (HPA). This deployment is part of a pipeline in which workers read messages from pubsub subscriptions, do some work and publish to the next topic. Right now I use a configmap to define the pipeline for the deployments (the configmap contains input subscription and output topics). The HPA autoscales based on the number of messages on the input subscription. I would like to be able to pull the subscription name for the HPA from a configmap if possible? Is there a way to do this?

example HPA:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: my-deployment-hpa
  namespace: default
  labels:
    name: my-deployment-hpa
spec:
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
    - external:
        metricName: pubsub.googleapis.com|subscription|num_undelivered_messages
        metricSelector:
          matchLabels:
            resource.labels.subscription_id: "$INPUT_SUBSCRIPTION"
        targetAverageValue: "2"
      type: External
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-deployment
```

The value from the HPA currently `$INPUT_SUBSCRIPTION` could ideally come from a configmap.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot.. but you can using prometheus-adapter + HPA . Check this 
 tuto : https://itnext.io/horizontal-pod-autoscaling-with-custom-metric-from-different-namespace-f19f8446143b

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI Thanks. Even there is seems like you would still be tied to hard coding the service name in the object metric of the HPA. If the HPAs cannot be dynamically configured themselves then I guess you are right, and that it won't be possible.

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI please provide your comment as an answer as it clarified what can/cannot be done with HPA.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer as a community wiki for a better visibility as well as the answer was provided in the comments.

Answering the question from the post:

> I would like to be able to pull the subscription name for the HPA from a configmap if possible? Is there a way to do this?

As pointed by user @Abdennour TOUMI there is no possibility to set the metric used by `HPA` with a `ConfigMap`:

> Unfortunately, you cannot.. but you can using prometheus-adapter + HPA . Check this tuto: [itnext.io/...](https://itnext.io/horizontal-pod-autoscaling-with-custom-metric-from-different-namespace-f19f8446143b)

---

As for a **manual workaround** you could use a script that will extract needed metric name from the `configMap` and use a template to replace and apply new `HPA`.

With a `configMap` like:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: example
data:
  metric_name: "new_awesome_metric" # <-
  not_needed: "only for example"
```

And following script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# variables
hpa_file_name="hpa.yaml"
configmap_name="example"
string_to_replace="PLACEHOLDER"

# extract the metric name used in a configmap
new_metric=$(kubectl get configmap $configmap_name -o json | jq '.data.metric_name')

# use the template to replace the $string_to_replace with your $new_metric and apply it
sed "s/$string_to_replace/$new_metric/g" $hpa_file_name | kubectl apply -f -
```

> This script will need to have a `hpa.yaml` with the template to apply it as resource (example from question could be used with a change:
>
> - `resource.labels.subscription_id: PLACEHOLDER`

---

For more reference this HPA definition could be based on this guide:

> [Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Tutorials: Autoscaling-metrics: PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/autoscaling-metrics#pubsub_1)